# How to use ModelMapper (Spring Boot) to map nested objects into nested DTOs

Tags: java, spring, rest, nested, dto

I usually build my DTO mappers and just decided to learn how to use model mapper.
I have this DTO classes:

```
public class CityDTO {
    private NeighborhoodDTO[] neighborhoods;
    private String name;

... getters and setters ...
}

public class NeighborhoodDTO{
    private String name;
    private int postalCode;
    private BuildingDTO[] buildings;

... getters and setters ...
}

public class BuildingDTO{
    private int number;
    private String description;
    
... getters and setters ...
}
```

And these entities

```
public class City {
    private String name;
    private Neighborhood[] neighborhoods;
    ...
... other things ...
}

public class Neighborhood{
    private String name;
    private int postalCode;
    private Building[] buildings;
    ...
... other things ...
}

public class Building{
    private int number;
    private String description;
    ...
... other things ...
}
```

I would like to map this in other to build a response to an API REST call that results in a json with this structure:

```
{
    "name": "New York",
    "neighborhoods": [
                      {"name": "Brooklyn",
                       "postalCode": 12345,
                       "buildings":[
                                    {"number": 1,
                                    "description": "house"},
                                    {"number": 2,
                                    "description": "hospital"},
                                    ...
                                   ]},
                       {"name": "Queens",
                       "postalCode": 98765,
                       "buildings":[
                                    {"number": 1,
                                    "description": "bar"},
                                    {"number": 2,
                                    "description": "school"},
                                    ...
                                   ]},
                       ...
                     ]

}
```

I know how to map entities inside entities but not when the DTOs are nested too and otherwise the resulting json is not clear.